# v-if is not reactive in tbody?

Tags: vue.js

when dataTable variable has data, v-if is not update itself?

```
 <tbody>
      <template v-if="dataTable">
           <tr is="devicesRow" v-for="(data,index) in dataTable" :data="data" :index="index" :key="index"></tr>
      </template>
       <template v-else>
           <tr class="text-center" >
            <td class="text-center" colspan="6"><b-spinner  style="width: 4rem; height: 4rem;" variant="primary" type="grow" label="Spinning"></b-spinner></td>
          </tr>
       </template>
     </tbody>



 computed:{
     dataTable:function(){return this.$store.getters.returngetdevices;}}
```

Comment: The general approach to tackle this issue is: `v-if="dataTable.length"`

Answer (score 2):

Please check if dataTable's datatype is a primitive type like number, strings or boolean then it will check boolean if it has non-primitive type like array or object then it will not check boolean.

If datatable is an array please use if `dataTable.length` or `dataTable !== false` . if dataTable will be empty it will coerce into false and if dataTable has values it will return true.

Comment: but when I pass another page and  come back, it is okay about data, by the way dataTable is an array

Comment: If data table is an array please use if "dataTable.length" or "dataTable != false" . if dataTable will be empty it will coerce into false and if dataTable has values it will return true

Comment: in vue devtools I have been looking what dataTable has as value but although dataTable has length v-if does not update itself?

Comment: you are getting dataTable from store and store will only update when state will change

Comment: You should tell us HOW you update your `dataTable` array. What does `this.$store.getters.returngetdevices` do?

Comment: in this page ı call an api request in created hook                                       created(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getdeviceswithLocation')
     },                                                                                                                                                                              and ı get the data from store by api request which is above, I mean calling api  and getting data from store are being doing in the this page

Comment: you should call api in mounted hook

Comment: you are calling api in created thats why it's not updating the state

Comment: Even when he calls the function in the `mounted` hook he's problem will still occur. I think we are dealing with an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. The `getdeviceswithLocation` function in the store is where the real problem resides.

Comment: please dispatch your action in mounted

Comment: does not change anything.